# Why does this Java code output "3210123"?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void downup(int n) {
    System.out.println(n);
    if(n>0) {
        downup(n-1);
        System.out.println(n);
    }   
}
```

I saw this code and do not understand why the output is 3210123 when n is 3. I can only understand that it has to be "3210". What about the rest of the output ("123")?

Comment: You have two `System.out.println(n);` lines in there. Think about when each of those is executed (and what value `n` has at those times)

Comment: You should trace it. :D

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: In my opinion n is at first for example 3 then 2 then 1 and then 0. When it is 0 how is the second System.out.println(n); excecuted?

Comment: Rephrasing a popular saying for this particular case: "Everything that goes down should eventually raise up".

Comment: @Bene200404 - It's not a question of "*opinion*". You have all means to see what **actually** happens.

Comment: @Bene200404 Why don't you try `downup(0)` to see what it prints, then try `downup(1)` to see what that prints?  That might help you understand the role of the second `println` call.

Comment: For this particular example, keep in mind that execution is sequential - each line is executed only after the previous line. Then consider what happens during a recursive call. Now, list the process by hand.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. These helped me alot. Now I understand how it works.

Comment: That which is called, must also return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exeuction can be visualized like this:

```text
downup(3)
    println(3)
    downup(3-1)
        println(2)
        downup(2-1)
            println(1)
            downup(1-1)
                println(0)
                condition false, recursion stopped
                return
            println(1)
            return
        println(2)
        return
    println(3)
    return
```

Every time `downup()` is called (recursively), indentation increases. When execution returns from `downup()`, indentation decreases.